# redirection from non www to www not working from .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, cloud, apache2

I have read many answers but nothing seems to work for me. I want to redirect non www domain to www, but it is not happening.

My **.htaccess** file in /home/ashish/mywebsite where my website code lies:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^getechready.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.getechready.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

**mywebsite.conf** file in /etc/apache2/sites-available:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
 
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    Alias /static /home/ashish/mywebsite/static
    <Directory /home/ashish/mywebsite/static>
    Require all granted
    </Directory>
    Alias /media /home/ashish/mywebsite/media
    <Directory /home/ashish/mywebsite/media>
    Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/ashish/mywebsite/mywebsite>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                    Require all granted
            </Files>
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/ashish/mywebsite>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ashish/mywebsite/mywebsite/wsgi.py
    WSGIDaemonProcess django_app python-path=/home/ashish/mywebsite python->
    WSGIProcessGroup django_app
    </VirtualHost>
```

**apache2.conf** in /etc/apache2 :

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

AccessFileName .htaccess
    <FilesMatch "^\.ht">
        Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```

when I write some gibberish on .htacess file website gives 500 error. so .htaccess files is being read but when I do curl -I getechready.com, it shows url not resolved and redirection aslo does not happen in browser.

I am using Python 3.8 and django 3.1.

Note: my document root is /var/www/html but my website code lies in /ashish/home/mywebsite , *where I have place .htacess file*

Please let me know in case any other data required.

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache.

Comment: @AmitVerma  I did, even ran 'sudo service apache2 restart' many times, but not working, I basically do 'curl -I getechready.com', it should give 301, but it is giving URL cannot be resolved

Comment: "when I do `curl -I getechready.com`, it shows url not resolved" - If the request doesn't "resolve" then it's not even reaching your server or the server is not accepting the request?

Comment: @MrWhite Yes that is the problem, I am not able to redirect the request even to my server using method mentioned in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not get any answer suitable for me from apache end,
So because I am using Django , what I did is added : `PREPEND_WWW = True` in settings.py file, just make sure you have `'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',` in your middlewares and remember to remove all the rules from .htaccess file. worked for me